# Getting first day of the month -1 month

Tags: php, date

How do I get the first day of the month in php? And the first day of one month early.
So as example:

$startdate = 01-05-2014
$enddate = 01-06-2014

The enddate has to be the first day of the current month so if it is 26-01-2014 the enddate is 01-01-2014

and the startdate is then 01-12-13

Comment: Look into `strtotime`.

Comment: The first day of any month is always day 1. So what exactly are you having trouble with? Did you read the [Date/Time section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) of the manual?

Comment: Good point @Jon first day of the current month could always be retrieved as date("Y-m")."-01";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you have the dates as a Timestamp, you can use this to get the first day of the month:

```
date("Y-m-1", $timestamp) ;
```

You can get the last day of a month, when you use:

```
date("t", $timestamp) ; // would give you 31 in January
```

In a complete example for your problem:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("26-01-2014") ;
$startdate = date("Y-m-1", strtotime("-1 month", $timestamp)) ; // to subtract one month -> use strtotime
$enddate = date("Y-m-1", $timestamp) ;
```

See also in the documentation of PHP for [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php).